# 413 Request Entity Too Large in DigitalOcean (Nginx)

Tags: nginx, digital-ocean

I am facing this issue (**413 Request Entity Too Large**) in Ubuntu 18.04.
I am using **NGINX** server ,Digital-ocean Cloud.
I have done changes in php.ini ,to upload max file size to 128MB.
But i think i need to do some configuration in nginx .
Can anyone suggest me what configuration should i do.

Answer (score 8):

I added **client_max_body_size 128M;** in side http{} block in nginx.conf  file, now this issue is solved.

Comment: After updating upload_max_filesize and post_max_size in php.ini, with no luck, adding client_max_body_size to /etc/nginx/nginx.conf and restarting was the trick on Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 2):

In nginx add inside `server { }`  `client_max_body_size 128M;`.

In php config change `upload_max_filesize = 128M` and `post_max_size = 129M`.

Comment: you want to say that , in nginx.cong file i should add server { part client_max_body_size 128M; }

Comment: In php config change upload_max_filesize = 128M and post_max_size = 128M., I have done this before only ,after this only i am getting this issue

Answer (score 0):

### On Kubernetes

You can use the annotation `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size` to set the `max-body-size` option right in your Ingress object instead of changing a base ConfigMap.

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-app
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "50m"
...
```